# Is it safe to use a C# static class as a means of sharing data from one azure function to another?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, static-classes

I have two functions under a Azure function plan. Also included in there is a static class with a public static string. Can I use this static string as a means of transferring data from one function to the other?

The main concern I have is regarding instances. If each trigger creates a new copy of the static class and its string content then I believe this shouldn't be a problem. So does each trigger of the first function that calls the static class create a new copy for itself of it or is it shared among different simultaneous function clients?

Should I look for an alternative approach like Redis cache or something similar?

Comment: You don't instantiate a static class. Static classes are used to provide methods which don't require an object to be created.

Comment: Maybe this will help you understand a static class better (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/74ce7b/static-class-in-C-Sharp/)

Comment: Yes sir true. But my question is about sharing this same static class string among different instances of the azure function i.e. two clients trigger the azure function which has code in to to insert data into the static string (inside the static class). Will each client have his/her own copy of the static string field or will it be shared among them creating conflict in data transfer to the second function? I will edit the question too. sorry....

Comment: Have you considered how your going to deal with race conditions? What happens when multiple threads access this "state" at the exact same instant, etc? Tl;dr you could possibly do this but there almost certainly are better options

Comment: *So does each trigger of the first function that calls the static class create a new copy for itself* no there is only ever one **in any given process**

Comment: *Should I look for an alternative approach like Redis cache or something similar* yes

Comment: Azure Functions and AWS Lambdas are different *processes*, running on different machines. Static classes have nothing to do with sharing data between processes

Comment: If you want to share data between processes, you either pass it on each call, or you store it in a common storage. It's the same with AWS Lambdas and Azure Functions. If you want to pass data to another function, pass it in the call. If you want to keep the data for future use, use a shared storage like a database, Redis, a file on Blob storage, a queue etc

Comment: I would assume you have no guarantee that two function invocations will run in the same process and thus no guarantee that your "shared state" is really shared at all.

Comment: It works now as it is. The static classes public string is able to retrieve a value from the first function and I am accessing this value in the second function. I am just worried what happens when there are multiple requests at the same time. I guess I have to heed to Liam's advice and look into caching of some sort. I am unable to depict my scenario clearly. Sorry...

Comment: @Gowthaman it doesn't work now at all except by accident, unless you mean something completely different when you talk about Azure Functions. Perhaps the traffic is so low that only a single instance is used. Perhaps the Function is used for so little time that you don't realize it won't live beyond 10-15 minutes

Comment: Well now I understand what a process is :) and so far both the function's invocation are happening as part of the same process. So assuming its always a singular process what happens when numerous process requests are submitted. Then we will have different copies of the static class and thus my solution is safe as it is now yes? :)

Comment: @Gowthaman no and no. The assumption is 1000% wrong. AWS Lambdas and Azure Functions will spawn a *new instance* if one process is busy while another request arrives

Comment: Yes the only traffic is my testing so far.....

Comment: @Panagiotis "AWS Lambdas and Azure Functions will spawn a new instance if one process is busy while another request arrives". Okay thats good news. Now the only other thing I need to verify is if both the functions be part of the same process all the time. Is there a way to ensure that this is true at all times?

Comment: Also I wanted to point out both the functions and the static class are inside the same project in VS from where I am publishing. Do you know of any documentation that explains such file sharing scenario's?

Comment: Never, ever assume multiple instances of an azure function share the same process. Even if they do now it migh be changed in the future. Use a proper (nosql) store. If two functions need to communicate with each other use a store. Period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure function is serverless. If you are running under a consumption plan multiple function instance will start executing and when instance is idle, it will release instances.

Maintaining state outside function is best approach.

I used Redis for same and seen lot of performance improvement in my application. If you have frequent read/write Redis is best option and you have to pay a dedicated amount for Redis instance.

If function request is not very frequent or budge is constant, you can use "Azure Storage Table" as well. you don't need to pay a dedicated amount.

Comment: +1 for Redis. If you want to save money while developing you can also install Redis on a Linux VM and shutdown the VM while you're not using it to save money.

It's also worth mentioning you could store a JSON file on Azure Blob Storage, not ideal but extremely cheap. You may get some latency issues with this approach however.

Comment: Developers can install Redis in local machine for development.

Answer (score 0):

**Azure Functions** offers an alternative for creating **stateful functions** called Durable **Functions**. Durable **Functions** is an extension to the **Azure Functions** runtime that enables the definition of stateful workflows in code.

For more information follow the below docs.

**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serverless-architecture/durable-azure-functions
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview**

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve what you are trying to do is to use queues with payloads.

Basically one functions puts the data you want to transfer in a queue. The other function has a Queuetrigger that once a message shows will run (being able to access the data)

Comment: Good idea. But unfortunately my second function is also User HTTP Triggered. So I guess storage table would be the best option for me....